# hibernate.cfg.xml cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist. NetBeans Spring MVC Hibernate web app error

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat, netbeans

I work with NetBeans 12.5 project for Web App, using Spring-MVC, Hibernate, and Tomcat 8 as an application server

I build the project to WAR file and try to run WAR file via tomcat and get the error below.

1234 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
1234 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

applicationContext.xml

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"></property> 
    </bean>
```

My "hibernate.cfg.xml" location : src\java

My project Structure:
[Proj_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cll8j.png)

I changed the code value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" to value="classpath:java/hibernate.cfg.xml"
and run WAR file via tomcat again, it come with new error below:

1386 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE
1392 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE

Please help me, Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked if it exists in your `war` archive? Most likely it doesn't. try moving it to `src/main/resources` if you follow a maven project structure, else edit your question and post also your project structure.

Comment: I didn't use maven project

Comment: does hibernate.cfg.xml exists in your war? it is easy to check it

Comment: I found it in WEB-INF\classes\java

Comment: hibernate.cfg.xml is exists in my war file

Comment: maybe you have to alter `value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"` since there is a `java` " folder" in its location as per your comment. try `value="classpath:java/hibernate.cfg.xml"`

Comment: I've modified the code follow your suggestion and it has new error. Please check my updated question, do you know how to fix it ?